# Mongoose does not update my array in the database

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update my collection with mongoose.

This is my Schema:

```
var FamilySchema = mongoose.Schema({
construction: {
    type: Array,
    default: [
        ["foundry", 0],
        ["farm", 0],
        ["sawmill", 0]
    ]
}
});
```

And this is my code:

```
app.put('/construction/updateConstruction/:id', (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;

Family.findById(id, (err, familiaDB) => {

    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }

    if (!familiaDB) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }

    // I want to update the value of the posicion 0 in the array.
    familiaDB.construction[0][1] = 1;
    familiaDB.save();
    console.log(familiaDB);

});
});
```

Result in console.log after making the request:

```
Escuchando puerto:  3000
Base de datos ONLINE

{ state: true,    
construction:
[ [ 'foundry', 1 ],
 [ 'farm', 0 ],
 [ 'sawmill', 0 ],
_id: 5bb8d69c604625211c572ada,
__v: 0 }
```

In console.log everything is fine and updated, but in my db it is not updated. I have checked it many times in robomongo and never updates it.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this would be with [**findOneAndUpdate**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html):

```
Family.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("YOURID") }, 
  { $set: { 'construction.0.1': 'YourValue'  }}
)
```

This will do it in one statement.

Now instead of doing this by index you can do it with [**$elemMatch**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and update the correct one via:

```
Family.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: ObjectId("YOURID"), 'cons': { $elemMatch: { '0': 'foundry' }}}, 
  { $set: { 'cons.$.1': 'YourValue' } }
)
```